# Trying to use deferred objects and $.when to make multiple AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So, based off of this tutorial on Medium (https://medium.com/coding-design/writing-better-ajax-8ee4a7fb95f#.d7ymg99mp), I am trying to use deferred arrays, ajax requests and jQuery.when method to make multiple ajax requests and obtain the result from each one of them.

Here is the code for what I am doing

```
function updateAllGoingButtons(){
    var dataToPass = {};
    var deferreds = [];

    $('.btn-group').find('button').each(function(){
       console.log($(this).attr('id'));
       dataToPass.button = $(this).attr('id');
       var ajax = $.ajax({
          url: '/update-buttons',
          method: 'post',
          data: dataToPass,
          dataType:'json'
       });

       deferreds.push(ajax);

       $.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function(){

       });
    });
}
```

My confusion arises as to how to use this $.when function and where I can access the data returned to the ajax call.

I tried inserting a simple success option, but that didn't enter its callback function. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You're just calling `when` too soon. Do it **outside** the `each` loop, after you've started all your ajax calls and gotten their promises in the array:

```
function updateAllGoingButtons(){
    var dataToPass = {};
    var deferreds = [];

    $('.btn-group').find('button').each(function(){
       console.log($(this).attr('id'));
       dataToPass.button = $(this).attr('id');
       var ajax = $.ajax({
          url: '/update-buttons',
          method: 'post',
          data: dataToPass,
          dataType:'json'
       });

       deferreds.push(ajax);

    });

    $.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function(){     // <=== Moved this
                                                    // <===
    });                                             // <===
}
```

The results of those ajax calls will be provided to your `then` function as a series of discrete arguments. Each argument will be an array with three entries, corresponding to the three arguments normally passed to `success` functions. Since you're dealing with an array, you'll probably want to access them via the `arguments` pseudo-array. It's also always a good idea to have a rejection handler (the second argument to `then`, or alternately use `catch` with recent versions of jQuery):

```
$.when.apply($, deferreds).then(
    function() {
        var n;
        for (n = 0; n < arguments.length; ++n) {
             console.log("Result " + n, arguments[n][0]);
        }
    },
    function() {
        // At least one request failed
    }
);
```

Comment: Okay, but I still don't get how to access data passed back to the AJAX call from inside the $.when method! How do I do that? When I try to console.log(deferreds) from inside that method, I don't get any output.

Comment: @ZaidHumayun: As it says in the [`when` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/): *"The arguments passed to the doneCallbacks provide the resolved values for each of the Deferreds, and matches the order the Deferreds were passed to jQuery.when()."* (which is followed by an example; search for "pizza" on that page). Basically: The results are discrete arguments to the callback.

Comment: Well, I seem to be misunderstanding this. In the documentation, it looks like the Deferred objects are explicitly being resolved, whereas I am simply using res.send to return data. Will my case still work? Because I tried passing parameters and logging them within the then callback, but no luck.
`$.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function(a,b,c,d,e) {
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
        console.log(c);
        console.log(d);
    });`

Comment: @ZaidHumayun: Yes. In that example, they're creating and resolving the deferreds, but in your use case, you're using the ones created and resolved by `ajax`.

Comment: Well, then my console.log should be logging out the response right? Why is that not happening? Am I not using it right? When I try to use console.log(some value), I don't get anything in the output, but I don't get an error either.

Comment: @ZaidHumayun: Yes, you should be seeing something from those console.log statements if the calls were all successful; I do: https://jsfiddle.net/57z7qycL/ Sounds like an error is occurring in at least one call. Since you're not passing a second function to `then`, you're not getting notified of the error. Note that each result, in the case of ajax, is an array with three entries (which correspond to the three arguments `success` would normally get, so you typically want `[0]`).

Comment: I noticed that if I changed my res.send("Okay") to res.json("Okay") in my router file, my success chain console logs Okay 10 times (see edit to original code). However, I still can't seem to access the parameters within the $.when method, despite trying to access the 0th index of the array. 
How do I handle errors within that method just to make sure nothing is going wrong?